# pbkdf2withhmacsha1 en java y python

Tags: java, python, hash

Estoy intentando llegar al mismo resultado con un hash para contraseña que utiliza pbkdf2withhmacsha1

en java tengo el siguiente codigo

```js
 public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final int ITERATIONS = 1000;
        final int HASH_SIZE = 24;
        final String s = "123abc";
        final String salt = "FF3BFFD6E104F12B6A406744145E6FB54E0674C61888A192";
       
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(s.toCharArray(), DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(salt), ITERATIONS, 48);
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        
        String result = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded());
        
        
        System.out.println(HASH_SIZE * Byte.SIZE);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

y me arroja de resultado

> FA1AE4DECD3E52345E8A840FB8E38723505CC04EAA2CE826

en python tengo el siguiente codigo

```js
> 
    from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
from binascii import hexlify

key = pbkdf2_hmac(
    hash_name = 'sha1',
    password = b'123abc',
    salt = b'FF3BFFD6E104F12B6A406744145E6FB54E0674C61888A192',
    iterations = 1000,
    dklen = 24
)

print(key.hex())
```

y me arroja de resultado

> bd68c7b9d53adf9cf72805db293a4b3bd7c0d1d0e1b19a0f

Que estoy haciendo mal para que me de el mismo resultado en ambas, tomando como base el codigo de java que es el que esta guardado en la BD